# JS causing links in navbar list elements to not work, how can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a website with a free template and i dont know JS really well. So i made a research and figured JS causing the problem.

So here is the relevant HTML and JS codes:

```js
var clickMenu = function() {

  $('#navbar a:not([class="external"])').click(function(event) {
    var section = $(this).data('nav-section'),
      navbar = $('#navbar');

    if ($('[data-section="' + section + '"]').length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[data-section="' + section + '"]').offset().top - 55
      }, 500);
    }

    if (navbar.is(':visible')) {
      navbar.removeClass('in');
      navbar.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
      $('.js-fh5co-nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });


};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
      <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i></i></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span>X</span>XXX XXXX</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html" data-nav-section="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="about"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the function, the `return false;` statement is triggering on every link; regardless of whether it's an in page anchor, or linking to another page. This will prevent the browser from jumping to other pages.

I've changed your (relevant) code around some, and posted some new jQuery (with comments):

The target was removed from `data-nav-section`, and placed directly into the `href`. This reduces some superfluous code, as well as makes it so these will function on browsers without script support. Instead of a nice scroll, they will simply jump. But - since the JS is being used to stop the browser's functionality - browsers with script support will function fine.

I am using `rel="external"` instead of 'class="external"`, because`class`is only useful to CSS;`rel` can be used just as easily by CSS, but can also be interpreted by automated systems (like bots and search engines).

I've also replaced the `class="active"`, with `aria-current="page"`. Again, CSS works with both equally well, but `aria-current=""` works with accessible systems (i.e. screen readers).

**NOTE:** I am unsure what the `if (navbar.is(':visible')) {...` code block is for, so I have left it out of my example for now.

```js
$('document').ready(() => {

  $('#navbar a:not([rel="external"])').on('click', function(event) {
    // Assign target element to the variable targetElement.
    let targetElement = $("#" + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1]);

    // If the target element exists, it will have a length. If it doesn't exist, the browser will do its own thing.
    if (targetElement.length) {
      // Scroll browser window to the top of the element (-55px)
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: targetElement.offset().top - 55
      }, 500);
      // End funtion processing, and prevent the browser from performing any more actions.
      return false;
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
      <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i></i></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span>X</span>XXX XXXX</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li aria-current="page"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"><span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services"><span>Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="about" style="height: 200px; width=900px; background-color: #0F0;">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="services" style="height: 200px; width=900px; background-color: #00F;">
      <h2>Services</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="contact" style="height: 200px; width=900px; background-color: #F00;">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```